# Zurb Foundation columns getting stacked

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have two columns in a row. But the two columns are being stacked vertically.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>



<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 columns"><p>2 columns</p>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns"><p>10 columns</p>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The 2 column div and the 4 column div should appear side by side but are instead stacked on below the other.

Answer (score 0):

What your telling your code is to set a column of 2 (blocks)  width and then 4 (blocks) width, which adds up to 6.

Whereas you need to have the whole row (its parts thereof) add up to 12. There are various number combinations you could use to get to 12, but for simplicity we'll use your commented values.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns"><p>2 columns</p> </div>
    <div class="small-10 columns"><p>10 columns</p> </div>
</div>
```

Or we can use your ratio sizes to give the look of what I think you were trying to achieve.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns"><p>1/3 width in columns</p> </div>
    <div class="small-8 columns"><p>2/3 with columns</p> </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you with your question.